# Determine attributes of an Schannel connection -> returns unknown value

Tags: windows, network-programming, schannel

After successfully [Creating a Secure Connection Using Schannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374782), I am obtaining its connection attributes using [QueryContextAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379340)(), passing `SECPKG_ATTR_CONNECTION_INFO`.

The returned structure `SecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo` contains the field `aiExch`, which holds the information I am looking for - namely the used key exchange algorithm.

I am using this for months, and it always returned one of the two predefined values `CALG_RSA_KEYX` or `CALG_DH_EPHEM.` But since a couple of weeks (when I believe a Schannel update patch was issued by Microsoft) it returns an unknown value: `0x0000ae06`

Using these macros, the ALG_ID can be split into its components:

```
#define GET_ALG_CLASS(x)                (x & (7 << 13))
#define GET_ALG_TYPE(x)                 (x & (15 << 9))
#define GET_ALG_SID(x)                  (x & (511))
```

According to that, `0x0000ae06` would mean:

Class: `ALG_CLASS_KEY_EXCHANGE`
Type: `(7 << 9)` -> which is undefined
SID: `6` -> whose meaning depends on the type of algorithm

Anyone ran into the same issue? Can anyone explain what happened, or what `0x0000ae06` stands for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code found here http://pastebin.com/TKQJ85Z9 notice that, the ID was added to the schannel library but apparently the VC headers weren't update, at any rate, as you can see from the above code (see pastebin URL), that ID corresponds to "ECDHE", that is Elliptic Curve DH with Ephemeral key exchange

[edit]

The real problem is that the value is unofficial and can only be found by some internet search, that's why I posted the link to some sample code; see, it just happened to me to find the answer by looking at this twit https://twitter.com/ericlaw/status/301083494203928576

At any rate, it sounds like the latest version of the Microsoft CNG SDK contains updated headers and libraries which add a new constant for the "**QueryContextAttributes**" API call, that is **SECPKG_ATTR_CIPHER_INFO** such a call returns a structure (see definition in code below) whose member named "**szCipherSuite**" reports the full string for the cipher in use, for example "**TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384**"

Here's some sample code for such a call

```
/*
// -- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1251
typedef struct _SecPkgContext_CipherInfo
{

    DWORD dwVersion;
    DWORD dwProtocol;
    DWORD dwCipherSuite;
    DWORD dwBaseCipherSuite;
    WCHAR szCipherSuite[SZ_ALG_MAX_SIZE];
    WCHAR szCipher[SZ_ALG_MAX_SIZE];
    DWORD dwCipherLen;
    DWORD dwCipherBlockLen;    // in bytes
    WCHAR szHash[SZ_ALG_MAX_SIZE];
    DWORD dwHashLen;
    WCHAR szExchange[SZ_ALG_MAX_SIZE];
    DWORD dwMinExchangeLen;
    DWORD dwMaxExchangeLen;
    WCHAR szCertificate[SZ_ALG_MAX_SIZE];
    DWORD dwKeyType;
} SecPkgContext_CipherInfo, *PSecPkgContext_CipherInfo;
*/    

static void DisplayConnectionInfo(CtxtHandle *phContext)
{
  SECURITY_STATUS Status;
  SecPkgContext_CipherInfo CipherInfo = { SECPKGCONTEXT_CIPHERINFO_V1 };

  Status = QueryContextAttributes( phContext, SECPKG_ATTR_CIPHER_INFO, &CipherInfo);    
  if(Status != SEC_E_OK) 
  { 
    printf("Error 0x%x querying cipher info\n", Status); 
    return; 
  }

  printf("%S\n", CipherInfo.szCipherSuite);
}
```

for further infos, please get the MS CNG SDK and have a look at the included help and headers.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful information, difficult to find anywhere else. I have just written some [Delphi/FreePascal code to retrieve the information](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/commit/5277943fbbdfcce14e071ce0f049da7325c8a4d9) with a fallback on XP/2003 to the previous SECPKG_ATTR_CONNECTION_INFO.

Comment: Note that  `_SecPkgContext_CipherInfo.dwProtocol` seems incorrect (at least on Windows 7): it does not match `SecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo.dwProtocol`, which seems to provide the correct information.